# Number of Possible Pairs from Two Sets

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

The Question:

> We have 18 distinct gadgets and 22 distinct widgets. We want to pick five
>   pairs, each with one gadget and with one widget. In how many different
>   ways can the five pairs be chosen?

My Answer:

There are $18 \choose 5$ ways to pick the gadgets and $22 \choose 5$ ways to pick the widgets. Then we want to find all the ways in which we can pair up the picked gadgets and widgets. Let's take a fixed gadget. We can pair it with five widgets. For the next gadget, we can pair it with four widgets, etc. So there are $5!$ ways to pair the gadgets with widgets, and $5$ ways to choose the way in which we order the gadgets to begin with.

So the total number of ways is $5! \cdot 5 \cdot {18 \choose 5} \cdot {22 \choose 5}$.

Does that look right? I'm sceptical of my answer.

Comment: A downvote within 15 seconds of me posting the question?

Comment: I wondered about that too, especially since you’ve offered a complete attempt at a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You’re right to be skeptical: you have an extra factor of $5$.

There are indeed $\binom{18}5\binom{22}5$ ways to pick $5$ gadgets and $5$ widgets. Now order the gadgets arbitrarily; there are $5!$ ways to line up the widgets next to them, so there are $5!\binom{18}5\binom{22}5$ ways to form the $5$ pairs. Once you establish some fixed ordering of the gadgets, you’re done with them: there is no $5$-way choice involved. The point is that it doesn’t actually matter what ordering of the gadgets you use: each one leads to the same $5!$ possible pairings.

As a check, there are $\binom{18}5$ ways to pick $5$ gadgets. Line them up. There are $22$ ways to pick a widget for the first gadget, $21$ ways to pick a widget for the second gadget, and so on, for a total of

$$\binom{18}5\cdot22\cdot21\cdot20\cdot19\cdot18=\binom{18}5\cdot\frac{22!}{17!}=\binom{18}5\binom{22}55!\;.$$

Comment: Ah, that's right. I over-compensated for the ordering of the gadgets. Thanks! I'll accept your answer when the 15-minute window closes.

Comment: @Newb: You’re welcome!